# SPF: что случилось с проектами openspf.org и trusted-forwarder.org

Tags: email, spf

Проверяю SPF таким способом:

```
echo '8.8.8.8 info@google.com' | spfquery -f -
```

В ответе получаю:

> Please see http://www.openspf.org/Why?id=info%40google.com&ip=8.8.8.8&receiver=spfquery

По ссылке сайт не доступен.

Смотрим справку о программе:

```
spfquery -help
```

Есть такая опция:

> -trusted <0|1>             Should trusted-forwarder.org be checked?

Сайт http://trusted-forwarder.org/ также не доступен.

Ощущение, что проект заброшен. Но [Пакет: spfquery](https://packages.debian.org/sid/spfquery) поддерживается. Не понятно.

Что случилось с этими проектами? Почему в программе фигурируют не рабочие сайты?

Comment: Судя по [обсуждению](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/bb5b30/openspfopg_seems_permanently_down_spf/) сайт давно прилег. Что случилось - не ясно. Но для настройки SPF есть [куча других инструментов](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=09ZDXbCAKILikgX5jpeIBA&q=spf+test+tool&oq=spf+test+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0i203l10.1434.3911..6495...0.0..0.120.993.6j4......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39i19j0i324j0i3j0i30j0i19j0i10i19.ZyPnxCwwAas)

Comment: @de_frag, спасибо за ссылку! Этот инструмент рабочий, поддерживаемый, но не понятно, почему сайты лежат, а в инструменте есть эти ссылки. По-хорошему их выпилить оттуда, либо поменять. Все инструменты типа `libmail-spf-xs-perl`, используют libspf2, что и в `spfquery`. `trusted-forwarder.org` похоже задумывался как реестр доверенных релеев, и проект умер... странные дела